# What is ^ operator in C++

Tags: c++

```
void bitWiseOperation(int a, int b, int c){
    
    // Your code here
    int d, e, f, g, h;
    d = a ^ a;
    e = c ^ b;
    f = a & b;
    g = c | (a ^ a);
    h = ~e;
    cout << d << "\n" << e << "\n" << f << "\n" << g << "\n" << h << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit-wise exclusive-or (XOR) which means each bit of the result is an ex-or of corresponding bits of arguments.

For example `10 ^ 3 == 9` because:

```
binary  decimal
1010       10
0011        3
----
1001        9
```